# Sleep a thread for an indefinite amount of time in Linux

Tags: c, linux

I want to make a thread sleep for an indefinite amount of time. The reason I want to do this is because my program only takes action when it receives a signal and has nothing to do in the primary thread. Therefore, all processing is done inside the signal handler. How can I sleep for an indefinite amount of time?

Comment: Are you actually using threads, or just signals? If threads, what are the other threads and what are they doing? (If you're mixing signals and threads there's some extra work to do, but if you're just using "primary thread" to mean the part of the program that isn't executing in a signal handler, that's different and implies a different answer)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the `pause` function:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pause.html

You could do something like: `for (;;) pause();`

Comment: You don't need an infinite for loop, just use `pause();`.

Comment: @boramalper: The loops is needed because `pause` returns on signals.

Answer (score 8):

If you're just doing something on another thread, simply call `pthread_join` on that thread and it will pretty much block "forever". You could achieve the same effect using a condition variable.

Comment: I agree with Chris.  He's suggesting you have the main thread wait for the child thread(s) to exit, then exit itself.  This will not only do what you want, but prevent zombies if the child thread dies or gets killed.

Comment: That is a brilliant solution, Chris! Thanks!

Comment: Threads cannot be killed, and don't become "zombies" in the same sense as processes. If you don't care to join a thread, simply detach it to begin with so you don't have to worry about cleaning up the thread descriptor.

Answer (score 4):

Use semaphores!

Have your thread blocked on a semaphore by using `sem_wait`. Once you need to wake your thread signal the semaphore by using `sem_post` from another thread.

Answer (score 1):

POSIX provides the `sigsuspend` function to wait for a signal. (As mentioned in another answer, `pause` works as well.)